# How to reset column filters in PrimeReact Datatable?

Tags: reactjs, datatable, primereact

I am trying to figure out how to create a button to reset the column filters in PrimeReact Datatable. I am able to click the button and have the sorting be rest on the table, but the value in the column sort filed remains. How do I reset the value too?

I've tried a ton of things, below is the latest attempt...

```
const resetFilters = () => {
    console.log('filters', dt.current.getFilters());
    let filters = dt.current.getFilters()
    for (const filter in filters){
        dt.current.filters = filters[filter].value = '';
    }
    dt.current.reset();
}
```

The '3' is not cleared out when `dt.current.reset()` resets the table filter.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you would easily enable\disable the filter on columns by controlling the `filter` property. You can use the state variable for this `filter` property and toggle that boolean state variable when button clicked. In that way even filters gets hidden for the column when `filter=false`

```
 const [filterEnabled, setFilterEnabled] = useState(true)

 <Column field="personId" header="PersonID" filter={fiterEnabled} />

// And call setFilterEnabled(false) when button is clicked to reset\disable the filters
```

Comment: This solution works! If you want to clear field (not disable filter), you can just set  filterEnabled back to true in componentDidUpdate. Bravo and thank you for this answer!